# How to make Switch button in Android fill width in TableRow

Tags: android, button, switch-statement

I need to use a Switch but I need it to fill the TableRow, it would half to ON and half to OFF.

How could I achieve that? Tried lots of combinations but no success.

I have:

```
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:checked="false"
    android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
    android:textOff="OCUPADO"
    android:textOn="LIVRE"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_bg"
    android:track="@drawable/track_bg" />
```

Resulting screen (is set ON):
[image]

Changing to:

```
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchStatus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:checked="false"
    android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
    android:textOff="OCUPADO"
    android:textOn="LIVRE"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_bg"
    android:track="@drawable/track_bg" />
```

Resulting screen:
[image]

Comment: `android:layout_width="match_content"`

Answer (score 0):

Make width of switch `match_parent`
Try this

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:checked="false"
        android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
        android:textOff="OCUPADO"
        android:textOn="LIVRE"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_bg"
        android:track="@drawable/track_bg" />
```

Comment: See my update, it just changed to the right side of the screen/row